# How to get neighbor character from selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var comment = 'this is a test';
```

Assume `this i` is selected, Now I need to `null` (left side) and `s` (right side). How can I get them?

---

I can get selected text like this:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}

var selected_text = getSelectionHtml();
```

Comment: I don't quite get your question. You've shown an example of a text to be selected as a JS string, but using code selecting from HTML? What should be the results, if you'd select `"is is"` from the text?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, my example isn't very clear ...! I mean was selecting from HTML. Actually I'm trying to create a toolbar for a markdown-editor. I want when user clicks on *`I`* icon, then check neighbor characters, if they are `*` then remove them, else append them around selected text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  // Check if there are any ranges selected.
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0 && selection.type == "Range") {
    // Text content of the element.
    var text = selection.anchorNode.textContent;
    // selection.anchorOffset is the start position of the selection
    var before = text.substring(selection.anchorOffset-1, selection.anchorOffset);
    // selection.extentOffset is the end position of the selection
    var after = text.substring(selection.extentOffset, selection.extentOffset+1);
    // Check if there are any letters before or after selected string.
    // If not, change before and after to null.
    before = before.length === 1 ? before : null;
    after = after.length === 1 ? after : null;
    console.log(before, after);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>this is a test</div>
```

To get two characters:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  // Check if there are any ranges selected.
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0 && selection.type == "Range") {
    // Text content of the element.
    var text = selection.anchorNode.textContent;
    // selection.anchorOffset is the start position of the selection
    var before = text.substring(selection.anchorOffset-2, selection.anchorOffset);
    // selection.extentOffset is the end position of the selection
    var after = text.substring(selection.extentOffset, selection.extentOffset+2);
    // Check if there are any letters before or after selected string.
    // If not, change before and after to null.
    before = before.length >= 1 ? before : null;
    after = after.length >= 1 ? after : null;
    console.log(before, after);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>this is a test</div>
```

Comment: May you please tell me how can expand your script for two neighbor characters? like this: selected-text: `a te`. L: `s{space}`, R: `st`

Comment: @Shafizadeh Just change `-1` to `-2` and `+1` to `+2`, and `=== 1` to `>= 1`.

Comment: I am having an odd issue with this solution. When I select a certain string, it will return the previous and following character correctly on the first click, but from there on, it will return either null or different characters from the anchorNode. As if it is changing the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this. All you need is `window.getSelection()`. This returns an object. You can get the surrounding text with `window.getSelection().anchorNode.data`, and get the index of the selection *within* that text using `window.getSelection().anchorOffset`. Putting this all together, we have

```
var selection       = window.getSelection();
var selectionText   = selection.toString();
var surroundingText = selection.anchorNode.data;
var index           = selection.anchorOffset;

var leftNeighbor  = surroundingText[index - 1];
var rightNeighbor = surroundingText[index + selectionText.length];
```

Note that you will get `undefined` instead of `null` when there is no neighbor character.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  var selection       = window.getSelection();
  var selectionText   = selection.toString();
  var surroundingText = selection.anchorNode.data;
  var index           = selection.anchorOffset;

  var leftNeighbor  = surroundingText[index - 1];
  var rightNeighbor = surroundingText[index + selectionText.length];

  alert(leftNeighbor + " " + rightNeighbor);
});
```

```html
<div>
this is a test
</div>
```

Comment: Only works if there are no parent nodes, ie <i><b> and other tags ( as in question ). Things will get rough if you want to extend 'this <i>is</i> a test'

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other two solutions is they both work if the user selects from left to right, but not if they select right to left. As such, I use this modified version:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
const text = selection.anchorNode.textContent;
let beforeChar;
let afterChar;
if (selection.anchorOffset < selection.focusOffset) {
  beforeChar = text.substring(selection.anchorOffset, selection.anchorOffset-1);
  afterChar = text.substring(selection.extentOffset, selection.extentOffset+1);
} else {
  beforeChar = text.substring(selection.extentOffset, selection.extentOffset-1)
  afterChar = text.substring(selection.anchorOffset, selection.anchorOffset+1);
}
console.log(beforeChar, afterChar);
```