# Why getSelection() always returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("body").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var selection =  window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a test</textarea>
<button>click</button>
```

In the above fiddle, I expect to it return selected-text (in the textarea) when I click on that button, but it always returns nothing. How can I fix it?

**Note:** This doesn't work either:

`var selection =  window.getElementById("txtarea").getSelection().toString()`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `click` event happens when the mouse button is pressed, and then released, and at that time the selection is lost.

You have to use the `mousedown` event instead, which happens just when the mouse button is pressed, before the selection is lost

```js
function getSelection(elem) {
    var selectedText;

    if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
        elem.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    } else if (elem.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
        var startPos = elem.selectionStart;
        var endPos   = elem.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = elem.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    return selectedText;
}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  var selection =  getSelection( $('#txtarea').get(0) );
  alert(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a test</textarea>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Perfect solution ...! +1

Comment: As a suggestion: How does work a markdown editor when user click on *(for example)* `B`-icon? it uses `mousedown` or it saves the selection before the click, on other events *(as Amadan said in the comment)*

Comment: They generally use the `mousedown` event to get the selection, then replacing the selection with something like `<b>selected text</b>` etc. and then use `mouseup` to reset the focus back to the text, and mark the selection again.

Comment: I think I got it thank you .. I will start to create it .. And I guess I will encountered with some questions and I will ask again ;-)

Comment: @Oriol - that's a bug in Firefox with textareas and `getSelection`, it's well documented, the workaround is using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`

Comment: @adeneo Well how should I use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` exactly?

Comment: I guess I'll have to write the entire cross-browser version then

Comment: Look, I'm using your function to detect selected text, And after that I need to check neighbor characters using [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844005/how-to-get-neighbor-character-from-selected-text#34844138). But when I use of your selection, always the result is undefined. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: If you have some free time, please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846682/how-to-check-whether-surround-selected-text-characters-are-specific-characters) related question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't fix it, AFAIK - clicking anywhere removes the selection. Try without JavaScript: as soon as you click the button, or indeed anywhere, the selection disappears. Your code shows you the accurate state after that has happened.

Comment: So how a markdown editor append two stars `**` around selected text?

Comment: Without reading the code, I guess it saves the selection before the click, on other events.