# How to check what are adjacent characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a markdown editor and I need to check if neighbor characters are specific characters, then remove them, else append them.

For e.g I want to check selected-text, tow neighbor characters are `**`, then remove them, else append them around selected text.

---

I can get selected text using this approach:

```js
function getSelection(elem) {
    var selectedText;

    if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
        elem.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    } else if (elem.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
        var startPos = elem.selectionStart;
        var endPos   = elem.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = elem.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    return selectedText;
}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  var selection =  getSelection( $('#txtarea').get(0) );
  alert(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a test</textarea>
<button>Bold (toggle)</button>
```

Now I need when user clicks on that button, it checks if selected text is between `**` like this `**selectedtext**`, then remove them like this `selected text` else append them like this `**selectedtext**`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything I would like to refer to all the markdown editors out there: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20markdown%20library

So: do not try to reinvent the the wheel, and so on.

But for the sake of learning, my approach would look like this:

```
function toggleMarker(marker, el) {
var markerLength = marker.length;
var startPos, endPos, selection, range;

if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
    el.focus();
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    selection = range.text;
} else if (el.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
    startPos = el.selectionStart;
    endPos   = el.selectionEnd;
    selection = el.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
}

if (!selection.length){
        return;
}



if (el.value.substring(startPos-markerLength,startPos) === marker
        && el.value.substring(endPos,endPos+markerLength) === marker
){
        el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos-markerLength) +
                            selection + 
              el.value.substring(endPos+markerLength);
}
else{
        el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos) + marker + 
                            selection + marker + el.value.substring(endPos);
}

}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  toggleMarker( $(this).data('marker'), $('#txtarea').get(0) ).text;
});
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ro53v8/4/

The solution takes a very generic approach: the marker to toggle is set as a custom data attribute to make it easy to reuse the code.

The functionality is only implemented for the non-IE case. You will have to check, how to determine startPos and endPos for a range in IE.

In all other browsers:

1. the selection is identified
2. nothing is done if nothing is selected
3. sourroundings of the selection are checked against the given marker
4. if both markers are present, they get deleted
5. otherwise the markers are inserted

As a proof of concept this example works like a charm.
But there are some shortcomings:

- How to distinguish between bold text(**) and italics(*)?
- How to handle markers that just appear just on one side of the selection
- What to do, if a marker is selected?

But that is for you to solve now ...

Comment: Well played ...! Thank you +1

Comment: Just a small point .. Can you please use javascript variables instead of `data-marker` in HTML? I want all of that be in .js file. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you? This way you would have to write another action for each button or add a check for each case in the current one. by replacing `$(this).data('marker'` in  with any literal string (i.e. `'**'`) you could reduce the generic and reusable functionality to just what you are looking for. But again: Why would you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to find the occurance of a ** ** pattern.This regex will help you find the pattern similar to what you have.

`[*][*][a-z]*[*][*]` .

Using the `exec()` method, will help you extract that particular text.

Check the length of this using `.length`, if it is 4, then there is nothing in between, and you can replace it with the new text surrounded by `**`,

`"**"+ newtext+"**"`

For removing the **, you can use the `replace()` method, where you replace `**` with whitespace or so.